# I want to sort my api according to recent dates

Tags: reactjs

I have cards that render it from an api that has many objs including date and I wane to render the cards based on recent dates ...
What I need is to sort based on recent dates using react

snippets of code
also a link that works https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-glitter-ru6dvu?file=/src/App.js:166-207

my api https://api.npoint.io/d275425a434e02acf2f7

```
              {  filteredDate && filteredCat?.map((list) => {
               
                
                if (list.showOnHomepage === "yes") {
                  const date = format(
                    new Date(list.publishedDate),
                    "EEE dd MMM yyyy"
                  );
                  const showCat = news.map((getid) => {
                    if (getid.id == list.categoryID) return getid.name;
                  });
                  //  const rec = list.publishedDate.sort((date1, date2) => date1 - date2);

                  return (
                    <Card
                      className=" extraCard col-lg-3"
                      style={{ width: "" }}
                      id={list.categoryID}
                    >
                      <Card.Img
                        variant="top"
                        src={list.urlToImage}
                        alt="Image"
                      />
                      <Card.Body>
                        <Card.Title className="textTitle">
                          {list.title}
                        </Card.Title>
                        <Card.Text></Card.Text>
                        <small className="text-muted d-flex">
                          <FaRegCalendarAlt
                            className="m-1"
                            style={{ color: "#0aceff" }}
                          />
                          {date}
                        </small>

                        <div
                          style={{ color: "#0aceff" }}
                          className="d-flex justify-content-between"
                        >
                          <Button variant="" className={classes["btn-cat"]}>
                            {showCat}
                          </Button>
                          <div>
                            <FaRegHeart />
                            <p>
                              <FaLink />
                             <BrowserRouter>
                             {/* <Link to='./Newsitem.js'>
                                {''}
                              <button
                                
                
                              >Close</button>
                              </Link> */}
                             
                             </BrowserRouter>
                              {/* <button
                                onClick={() =>
                                  window.open("/src/components/News/Newsitem")
                                }
                              >
                                Go to another
                              </button> */}
                              <a
                                href="/Newsitem"
                                target="/src/components/News/Newsitem"
                                rel="noopener noreferrer"
                              >
                               
                                <button >Go to another page</button>
                              </a>
                            </p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                  );
                }
              })}
            </div>
          }
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use a state for you data which is coming from the server.
2. When getting the data, sort the News based on the publishedDate.
3. Set your state value.
4. Use your state value to render your UI.

Hope it helps:

```js
const [news, setNews] = useState([]);

const fetchNews = () => {
    fetch("https://api.npoint.io/d275425a434e02acf2f7").then((response) => response.json()).then((data) => {
        const sortedNews = data.News.sort(function(a, b) {
            const firstPublishedDate = new Date(a.publishedDate);
            const secondPublishedDate = new Date(b.publishedDate);
            return firstPublishedDate.getTime() - secondPublishedDate.getTime();
        });
        setNews(sortedNews);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
};

useEffect(() => {
    fetchNews();
}, []);

return (
    <div>
        {
            news.map((newsItem) => {
                return (
                    ...
                );
            })
        }
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can sort your `News` data in, for example, the `fetchDataList` call as shown below. This will sort starting from most recent articles at the top.

```
const fetchDataList = () => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    return fetch("https://api.npoint.io/d275425a434e02acf2f7")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            // sort news 
            data.News.sort(function(x, y) {
                if (x.publishedDate > y.publishedDate) {
                    return -1;
                }
                if (x.publishedDate < y.publishedDate) {
                    return 1;
                }
                return 0;
            });
            // **************
            setLists(data.News);
            setIsLoading(false);
        });
};
```

Here is a working snippet showing all of the API articles sorted:

https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-pond-0fr7jk

Comment: publishedDate is a string. So you can't compare the values by `>` or `<`.

Comment: @Amirhossein, given that his api endpoint has `publishedDate` all formatted the same YYYY-MM-DD, you can sort using this method, and it works as shown in the sandbox link. You could take the extra step to convert to `Date` but that step is left up to OP.

Comment: You're right but I think comparing dates which are strings is not a good option. The code is more clear and easy to read when converting them to Date objects for a new react developer.